# How to send textarea value as a parameter in a POST request

Tags: html, post, textarea

I am trying send the value of a textarea using a Post method when a button is clicked.

Code is very simple:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/editFile" name="confirmationForm" method="post">
<textarea id="confirmationText" class="text" cols="86" rows ="20"     name="confirmationText" form="confirmationForm">
 <out value="#{user.getFileContent}"/>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Email" class="submitButton" id=""/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

To get this data when this request is done I am using CWF web framework and the methode is very simple:

```
void editFileController::doPost(CWF::Request &request, CWF::Response    &response) const
{
  QString out = request.getParameter("confirmationText");//this will give me the value of the widget "confirmationText" from HTML
  QString out1 = request.getParameter("confirmationForm");
}
```

In order to get value of a filed this is done in this way:

```
<input type="file" name="test"/>
request.getPatameter("test"); //all works ok
```

But for the first example (the one with textarea) I can't set it to send the value of textarea when button is pushed.
Can anyone give me some ides about how I can fix this? This frameworks know only to give me the **value** for a specific **name**. So, somehow I should set the value of the button with the value of the textarea when this is pushed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea needs to belong to the form you are submitting.

Since you have `form="confirmationForm"`, it belongs to the form with `id="confirmationForm"` which doesn't exist.

**Remove the `form` attribute from the `<textarea>` start tag**.

---

Your form has `name="confirmationForm"`. The name attribute served a similar purpose to the `id` attribute before HTML standardized on `id` for client-side references to elements when HTML 4 came out in the late 1990s.

Two decades later, there is no reason to give elements `name` attributes for client-side purposes.

(Giving form *controls* like `<textarea>` `name` attributes for the purposes of submitting data for server-side use is still correct).

Comment: Hi @Quentin. That was the problem. Now it works, Thanks